# Squeak when changing to face or defrost

Tags: chevrolet, noise, hvac, silverado

Good afternoon I had a squeak that would happen when I turned my air to the face vent it would only squeak at the very end of the actuator cycle. Here is a link to the video of that https://youtu.be/K5ej1mt8xoU
I replaced the actuator which came with a new cam and the squeakisbetter but still there a little. It now also squeaks a little when you go to defrost at the very end of the actuator cycle. Here is the video for that https://youtu.be/88jC2iyLTE0 
Is this normal it doesn’t do it at certain temperatures which seems like to me the hvac box is expanding and contracting it’s on a 2011 Silverado 1500

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would bet you'd just need to grease where the actuator works on the flap. White lithium grease is probably the best choice. I've not taken the dash apart on a 2011 (or the like) Silvy to tell you *which one* to pull apart, however, they shouldn't be too hard to access.

Comment: I tried to spray it with silicone spray while the actuator was on but it didn’t help I might need to take it off and then spray. What do you think.

Comment: If you can use white lithium grease I think you'd be better off than with silicone spray. You may also need to hit the joints of the flap as well. This may entail you taking it apart to get at it.

Comment: The spray wont hold well to the heat of the vent. it will get runny and well run out. IF you can see the flap through the vent, rather than disassembling the dash, a q-tip taped to a chopstick may let you get some in and then move the vent to work it in.